# What are the correct Cassandra collection limits?

Tags: cassandra

I'm testing an application where the size of the collections is bound to grow in the future and 64k is a limit that may be reached in some cases.

This question is about the collection size limit as there seems to be a contradiction in the official documentation.

As per [this](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_collections_c.html) document:

> If you insert more than 64K items into a collection, only 64K of them
>   will be queryable, resulting in data loss.

But if you click through to the [CQL Limits link](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/refLimits.html) on that very page you see this:

> - Collection (List): **collection size: 2B** (2^31); values size: 65535 (2^16-1) (Cassandra 2.1 and later, using native protocol v3)
> - Collection (Set): **collection size: 2B** (2^31); values size: 65535 (2^16-1) (Cassandra 2.1 and later, using native protocol v3)
> - Collection (Map): **collection size: 2B** (2^31); number of keys: 65535 (2^16-1); values size: 65535 (2^16-1) (Cassandra 2.1 and later, using
>     native protocol v3)

So which one is it? 64k items per collection, or 2 billion items per collection? Or are 2 billion *writeable* but not readable beyond 64k?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Although this is slightly off topic do be aware that updating collections you need to be careful of how you implement it to avoid excessive tombstones, see this tech note: https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/205368125

Comment: Thanks for the observation @markc - I only use updates on all my set/list/map related queries. It just seems more natural.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

which version of cassandra you are using ?

that documentaion is for 2.0 and 2.1 . and in that case there is a limitation of how many elements you can put in a collection. which is 64k. however each element can have a size of 2b if you are using native protocol v3.
check this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5428

but if you are using cassandra 2.2 and later you can insert 2billion items into collection.
here is the link. http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCollections.html

having said that **you should not insert that many items into the collection. you will hit performance issues way before you hit the max elements insertion limit**.

`Collections cannot be "sliced"; Cassandra reads a collection in its entirety, impacting performance. Thus, collections should be much smaller than the maximum limits listed. The collection is not paged internally.`

If you have to have that much of item then in that case collections are not appropriate anymore and a specific table (with clustering columns) should be used.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is what I had inferred, but I wanted to make sure. Please note that both the documentation links I presented are for Cassandra 3.1, which means the documentation needs updating.

Answer (score 2):

You can't add more than 64k itens in cassandra collection if you are using cassandra 2.1. In this version, cassandra uses 16 bits to index elements. Otherwise, a single item can be 64k (in size) or 2B (depending on the protocol).

Comment: Oi Gustavo. Boa noite. Are you sure about this? The Cassandra docs seem to be ambiguous or not too clear about it. Why would they annotate the version number as having a higher limit  (Cassandra 2.1 and later, using native protocol v3)? Thanks again.

Comment: Actually, it depends the cassandra's version. This is true to cassandra 2.1 as said @root545. I will edit my answer.